# CORS not working on specific domains in firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors

```
const whitelist = ["http://mywebsite.com", "http://localhost:5000"]

const corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
      if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
        callback(null, true)
      } else {
        callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
      }
    }
  }

const cors = require('cors')(corsOptions);

exports.getUserProfile = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        try {
            //... here we fetch the user profile and send it in response
        } catch (err) {
            res.json({
                status: "error",
                message: err
            })
        }
    });
});
```

I'm using CORS in this way so I could only let my own website and localhost:5000 to make requests to the cloud functions that I'm using. localhost:5000 is for me so I could test stuff locally before I deploy the files.

1. Making a request from reqbin.com to my cloud function is working, why? Shouldn't it NOT work, since I've specified the domain to be either from mywebsite.com or localhost:5000?
2. Is there any other way to test stuff locally without having to include localhost:5000 in the whitelist? I'm using `firebase serve` to test, but I'm assuming this won't work since the requests won't be treated from mywebsite.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you by using origin from cors library directly.

```
const cors = require('cors')

const corsHandler = cors({
    origin:["http://mywebsite.com", "http://localhost:5000"]
});

exports.getUserProfile = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    corsHandler(req, res, async () => {
        try {
            //... here we fetch the user profile and send it in response
        } catch (err) {
            res.json({
                status: "error",
                message: err
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This did not work at all, even the requests from my own website didn't work, always throwing `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://users.mywebsite.com/api/getUserFavorites' from origin 'https://www.mywebsite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error in the console, I also added `https` version of my website in the whitelist.

Comment: you have to provide all subdomains and domains in this list.

Comment: I changed the `corsHandler` to `const corsHandler = cors({origin:["https://mywebsite.com","http://mywebsite.com","https://www.mywebsite.com","http://www.mywebsite.com","https://users.mywebsite.com","http://users.mywebsite.com","http://localhost:5000"]});` and this worked, but it also worked when I made a request from reqbin.com. :( Back to square one...

Comment: I can't imagine why this can happen, can you try logging origin at the backend? Maybe it changes somehow to one of the accepted ones?

Comment: @EmilGi I don't know how but this worked just now when I tried it again. No idea what happened, I re-deployed the whole firebase app and it worked (I was deploying only the functions with `firebase deploy --only functions`. Sigh. Thanks a lot for the help.